# Google Fit API - retrieving of fitness datasets

Tags: oauth-2.0, dataset, httprequest, http-request, google-fit

I am working on a web application which retrieves fitness data from the Google Fit REST API.
Everything worked fine until a few weeks ago. Now, Google Fit responds with a empty response body. So, the response contains absolute nothing. Google Fit returns a status code 200. I have changed nothing in my code which could have affected this.

I use this HTTP GET URL to request steps data:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas/datasets/1443869895588000000-1446465495589000000

When I use this URL to request fitness data in the OAuth Playground everything works fine.

I would be very thankful if someone has an idea how to fix this! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not use Rest api But I Used **History** API and **Session** API. Google respond error most of the time when the time interval you gave is wrong, or the data-type you are requesting are mismatched. Try checking it one more time which are the parameters you are sending in post.